# Add MessageText to the SMS SendLog data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

Is it possible to add custom fields such as mobile number and SMS message text to SMS SendLog data extension? The client is sending SMS using mostly Journey builder.

Thanks, Ivan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom Fields in a SendLog can be populated by the followings conditions

1. Matching field name in send log to field in the sendable DE
2. Matching field name in send log to attribute in Mobile Demographics
3. Matching field name in send log to ampscript var
4. Matching field name in send log to attributes passed in the API Call

So to solve your use case you could implement the following code

```
%%[ set @mobilenumber = _MobileNumber
    set @message = 'Thanks for joining our SMS program'
]%%

%%=v(@message)=%%
```

[Reference doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/personalizationStringsAMPscript.htm) for _mobilenumber

Comment: Very good answer, I really appreciate it. I think that the customer will not like this approach with setting the message text in a variable since they are planning to do some setup themselves. Would be nice if SF added this as a standard field in the SMS send log as an idea!