# SMS Preview for MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sendsmsactivity

I created an Outbound SMS message using ampscript, and performing a bulk send from a sendable DE.

I am logging some of the sendable DE values (used in ampscript above) to the SMSSendLog.

Is there a way we can 'preview' the SMS and then save it into the SMSSendLog (if possible) or to a custom DE.

Unrelated, if the _messagecontext = "SMS" will it solve my problem above. If so, can someone provide sample code.

Greatly appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: The sms message tracking data view has the complete render message

Comment: Hi EazyE - but I cannot use the view SMS Message Tracking view. I am looking for something realtime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add MessageText to the SMS SendLog data extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344225/add-messagetext-to-the-sms-sendlog-data-extension)